# PSD2 and PayPal Plus requirements

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment, psd2

Some days ago I read a new Magento bulletin:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/3D-Secure-2-0-changes/ba-p/136460
about PSD2 requirements.

Our customer uses only PayPal Plus (not the regular PayPal). But we don't find any pieces of information about this combination. In Germany, it is essential to fulfilling the PSD2 requirements, but the PayPal documents are very vague about this point.

Can anybody share his thoughts about these topics?

Thanks, Mario

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with Paypal Plus, but looking at this description it says

> For technical reasons PayPal Plus must be rendered in an iFrame.

So that seems that Paypal handle all the collection of data for payment, so should be OK, but I would contact paypal or the developer to confirm.

Also it looks like Germany are not enforcing the policy straight away (I used google translate, so maybe double check that is correct)

https://www.bafin.de/SharedDocs/Veroeffentlichungen/DE/Pressemitteilung/2019/pm_190821_PSD2_Kundenauthentifizierung.html